# Setup proxy in Mac OS X Lion Installer

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, install, internet, proxy

I have "restored" one usb stick with the BaseSystem.dmg of the InstallESD.dmg of my Lion installation and it boots. However it wants to connect to the internet to check the system requirements blablabla. Due to the fact, that i am currently at university where we use a proxy the network tool tells me that i have no connection. How can i set up the right proxy? Via the Terminal?

(Btw. the screen that opens is the Mac OS X Service Tools (don't know how to translate) which offers me to restore from Time Machine or to install Lion or to search online help. The Tools i can use are Firmware Password, Network tool and Terminal.)

Comment: Is your bootable OS 10.6 or 10.7? Either way, you'll need to enter the proxy settings there in the networking preference pane. Why not attach a screen shot or details of how you set up your proxy for a mac that runs? Someone might be able to help you with the terminal commands if you narrow down exactly the type of proxy in use.

Comment: @bmike: I am sorry, but i wanted to install a fresh system - not an upgrade - and therefore i formatted the HDD and have no system left on the MacBook. The reason why the installer wanted to connect to the App Store to check whether i have obtained the version legally. Being home now, i tried it again - where i do not need to enter proxy credentials! - and it worked fine. Nevertheless, thanks! (can be closed!)

Comment: This site is absolutely fine with anyone (even the asker) answering your own question. I would make an answer the best you can - you can then after two days accept it. Anyone can edit it later and you might help someone looking in the main Q/A and not in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Terminal and enter your proxy configuration using "networksetup".
For example

```
networksetup -setautoproxyurl Ethernet http://your.proxy.url/proxy.pac
```

"Ethernet" is the name of the network service, use

```
networksetup -listallnetworkservices
```

to see which name to use. If you don't use automatic proxy configuration, see "man networksetup" to see how to set up a manual configuration.

Then quit the Terminal and start the installation.

Comment: On most new Macs you'll use **"Wi-Fi"** or **"Thunderbolt Ethernet"** as appropriate for your network service name (the latter needs to be in those quotes as it has a space in its name)

Comment: Also may be worth noting the Terminal is available from the Utilities menu in the OS X installer (aka booting off the Recovery partition), only in the first screen (if you've clicked install you'll need to go back to the main menu to access it, at least in Mavericks)